# XOR/CNOT on 2 qubits in superposition - Deutsch

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

In an attempt to understand the design and to show that the Deutsch algorithm works with and only with sets of perpendicular qubits, my head got stock on this.

What is

$(|0⟩ - |1⟩) ⊕ (|0⟩ + |1⟩) = ? $

or more elaborate what is the result of the CNOT gate when a and b are in superpositions

CNOT$|a,b⟩→|a,a⊕b⟩$, having $a = (|0⟩ - |1⟩)$ and $b = (|0⟩ + |1⟩)$

this would help me formulate

$U_f(|a,b⟩→|a,a⊕b⟩)$, having $a = (|0⟩ - |1⟩)$ and $b = (|0⟩ + |1⟩)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how a certain gate acts on a certain basis then you can write your initial state as a linear superposition of states in that basis and use the fact that gates are linear operators.

For some given constant $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, you can write a linear combination like this :

$$|\psi\rangle=(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)(\gamma|0\rangle+\delta|1\rangle)=\alpha\gamma|00\rangle+\alpha\delta|01\rangle +\beta\gamma|10\rangle+\beta\delta|11\rangle$$

Now apply CNOT to each basis state
$$\mathrm{CNOT}|\psi\rangle=\alpha\gamma\;\mathrm{CNOT}|00\rangle+\alpha\delta\;\mathrm{CNOT}|01\rangle +\beta\gamma\;\mathrm{CNOT}|10\rangle+\beta\delta\;\mathrm{CNOT}|11\rangle$$
If the number to the left indicates the control qubit and the right the target qubit then you get:
$$\mathrm{CNOT}|\psi\rangle=\alpha\gamma|00\rangle+\alpha\delta|01\rangle +\beta\gamma|11\rangle+\beta\delta|10\rangle$$
If $\alpha=\gamma=\delta=1$ and $\beta=-1$, then you recover the same state $\mathrm{CNOT}|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial qubits are entangled, then the answer could be different. So I'll assume they're not entangled. Then the initial state is:

$$
|00\rangle + |01\rangle - |10\rangle - |11\rangle
$$

Applying $CNOT(a,b)$ flips the second bit whenever the first bgives the same state back again:

$$
|00\rangle + |01\rangle - |11\rangle - |10\rangle
$$

Comment: Also a good and direct answer